# In Python, how do I use subscriptions, or otherwise perform asynchronous operations?

Tags: python, async

I have the following code that polls for transactions every second. I want to make it more responsive, and not use polling, but instead something quicker.

```
tx_all_pending = w3.eth.filter('pending')
while True:
    pending_txs = tx_all_pending.get_new_entries()
    ...
    time.sleep(1)
```

In javascript, this is done using web3.eth.subscribe with a callback function. Is there something similar in Python? I realize I could change the polling rate to something like 1 millisecond, but that would be a drag on the CPU.

I've tried:

```
def new_tx(tx):
    ...

tx_all_pending = w3.eth.filter('pending')
tx_all_pending.watch(new_tx) # 'TransactionFilter' object has no attribute 'watch'
```

I've also tried:

```
async def main():
    block = await w3.eth.coro_getBlock(100) # 'Eth' object has no attribute 'coro_getBlock'

asyncio_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio_loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Thanks for any help.